# VisualForce page long text area missing on edit

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I've got a "long text area" field that I've put on a page (in edit mode) like this:

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="monkeys" mode="edit">
        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.JobIdRequestComments__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.LostDescription__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

The second of the two fields shows up just fine, but the first does not appear.  Any idea what to look at?  I don't see any difference between these fields in the field definitions, and the problem still exists when using the standardController with no extension.

As another test, I created a <apex:inputTextArea> on the same page, and when I put value="{!opportunity.JobIdRequestComments__c}", it doesn't get rendered, but when leaving that out, it does.

Comment: Have you checked basic stuff like field level security for your profile? What happens if you put {!$ObjectType.Opportunity.fields.JobIdRequestComments__c.accessible} somewhere on the page?

Comment: Argh!  I can't believe I missed something that obvious!

Comment: Hmm, can I mark your comment as the answer?  Or maybe you could answer it and I'll mark yours as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converting to answer (easy reputation ;))*

Have you checked basic stuff like field level security for your profile? Visualforce limits the field visibility based on this even if you're System Administrator and they're often left blank if for example you've deployed just the field / object definition without profiles.

What happens if you put `{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.fields.JobIdRequestComments__c.accessible}` somewhere on the page?